# Why is almond bark called almond bark?

Tags: almonds

[Almond bark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almond_bark) (the candy coating) seems to have no almond in it, why is it called almond bark?

Comment: I... I don't know. I was unfamiliar with the candy coating version of it, just with the "almonds on chocolate" version.

I checked the USDA and FDA regulations, since surely there was some regulation allowing the use of the word "almond" on a product with no almonds in it. No hits. I've sent emails to two of the major manufacturers, to see if they have any information.

Comment: It's anarchy! they shouldn't be able to just call it something that it isn't

Comment: It is a little odd. Usually there are specific regulations, or at least a ruling, with grandfather clauses for products that people are expected to understand and probably won't be confused. But if there's one in this case I couldn't find it, and I certainly was confused. It may just be that nobody has ever petitioned the USDA or FDA about it.

Comment: I agree, "almond bark" is a bad name. It's worse than "almond bite". 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to a representative from a company that makes it, it's packaged with the words “make your own almond bark".

So "almond bark" (the coating) is a key ingredient in "almond bark" (the candy with almonds). Over time, according to the representative, the ingredient became called with the same name as the candy.

Comment: The rep asked not to be quoted. (I should have asked before posting; I hadn't expected to be turned down. She's apparently very concerned that the answer might be interpreted in a context about allergens, which has potential legal ramifications.)

Comment: She asked not to be quoted, but I did update it to include a paraphrase that makes the answer more explicit.